# Use JQuery to populate a modal popup with a MVC4 partialview

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

This is driving me nuts. I'm having problems getting this to work. The dialog opens up, but the partialview is not loaded.  I have tried many of the examples here on SO, but to no avail.  Here's what I have so far.

My _layout.cshtml file has the following:

```
<div id="modal-content" name="modal-content"></div>
```

In my site.js I have the following:

```
$('#modal-content').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    position: { my: 'center', at: 'top+350', of: window },
    width: 'auto',
    height: 'auto',
    fluid: true,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    title: 'Create Guestbook Post',
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).load('@Url.Action("_Create")');
    },
});

$('#buttonCreateGuestbookPost').click(function() {
    $('#modal-content').dialog('open');
});
```

In the partialview (_Create.cshtml) I have the following:

```
@model MPP.Database.Guestbook
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="row">
        <h2>Create Account</h2>
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label float-left" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger float-right" })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </p>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label float-left" })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control float-right" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </p>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAddress, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label float-left" })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control float-right" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </p>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Body, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label float-left" })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Body, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control float-right" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Body, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" id="buttonCreateGuestbook" name="buttonCreateGuestbook" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create" />
        </p>
        }
    </div>
}
```

In the view that I want the popup to display to, I have the following button:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" id="buttonCreateGuestbookPost" style="margin-bottom:3px;">Post to Guestbook</a>
```

When the guestbook page loads, all of the components load properly (the button to open the dialog, the modal content DIV, the javascript to open/load the dialog, etc).  The problem is that when the button is clicked, the modal dialog opens but the partialview is not loaded.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says the code is in `site.js` but you are using Razor code in there for the url.

JS files are static and don't get compiled by Razor. Either hard code the url or pass it as a variable into your view so your script can access that variable.

Comment: Awe, nuts.  The examples is seen, the jquery code resided in the view. I outsmarted myself by moving it to an external file. This is why, I sometimes need a second pair of eyes.  Thanks.